# How to combine two .R files for simulating craps game?

Tags: r

Here are two R snippets of code for simulating craps (gambling) games, `craps.R` and `game.R` .

The following code's logic is: we play craps with one unit of bet. If I lose, I double my previous bet; if I win, I bet one unit again. Assume I started with 1000$ and one unit bet for 100$.

How can I combine these two files or what kind of command I could use to simulate the following code? I tried `source()`ing `game.R` after `craps.R`, or `print(craps())` in the console. I already installed the `random` package.

### craps.game.R

```
craps <- function() {
    field <- c(2,3,12)
    wins <- c(7,11)

    initialRoll <- as.integer(colSums(randomNumbers(2, 1, 6, 1)))
    if (initialRoll %in% field)
      out <- 0
    else if (initialRoll %in% wins)
      out <- 1
    else {
      point <- initialRoll
    # now run the game until you get 7 or point again
    roll <- 0
    while(roll!= point && roll!=7) {
      roll <- as.integer(colSums(randomNumbers(2, 1, 6, 1)))
    }
    if (roll == point)
      out <- 1
    else if (roll == 7)
      out <- 0
    out
    }
}
```

### game.R

```
balance<- 1000
bet <- 100
numGames <- 0

while(numGames < 10 && balance > 0)
   outcome <- craps()
if (outcome == 0) {
  balance <- balance - bet 
  bet <- min(balance, 2* bet)
} else {
  balance <- balance + bet 
  bet <- 100
}
  numGames <- numGames + 1
  cat("After game", numGames, "balance =", balance, "\n")
```

Comment: wrap the code after `while` in some curly braces and run the code. I made $700!

Comment: Yes, it works. I've tested these data, how do you think about this strategy in the craps games ?

Comment: It's a simple strategy, but seems to do ok. I ran it several times. Stock market probably a better gamble.

Answer (score 2):

You should include the necessary library calls in the script that needs them.

**craps.R**

```
library(random)  # added library call here

craps <- function() {
    field <- c(2,3,12)
    wins <- c(7,11)

    initialRoll <- as.integer(colSums(randomNumbers(2, 1, 6, 1)))
    if (initialRoll %in% field)
        out <- 0
    else if (initialRoll %in% wins)
        out <- 1
    else {
        point <- initialRoll
        # now run the game until you get 7 or point again
        roll <- 0
        while(roll!= point && roll!=7) {
            roll <- as.integer(colSums(randomNumbers(2, 1, 6, 1)))
        }
        if (roll == point)
            out <- 1
        else if (roll == 7)
            out <- 0
        out
    }
}
```

And you also need to wrap your `while` statement with curly brackets

**game.R**

```
balance<- 1000
bet <- 100
numGames <- 0

while(numGames < 10 && balance > 0) {  # added bracket here
    outcome <- craps()
if (outcome == 0) {
    balance <- balance - bet
    bet <- min(balance, 2* bet)
} else {
    balance <- balance + bet
    bet <- 100
}
numGames <- numGames + 1
cat("After game", numGames, "balance =", balance, "\n")
}  # added bracket here
```

And then call both scripts using the source command.

**main.R**

```
source('craps.R')
source('game.R')
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tested this system, do you think this strategy gonna work in the craps game?

Comment: Ah you're asking more of a statistical question than a coding question now. I might refer you to [cross validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) for some better insight on that. But I have heard of this strategy before, and that if you have very deep pockets and don't get scared you're very likely to at least break even.